# $\int_{\alpha}z^2 \log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz$ where $\alpha$ is $|z-1|=1$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Calculate

$$\int_{\alpha}z^2 \log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz$$

where $\alpha$ is $|z-1|=1$ and the initial point of integration $z_1=1+i$.

---

The function isn't analytic at $1$ and $-1$. Is there a theorem to solve it?

Transformation of the integral $z\to 1/z$

$$f(z)=\frac{\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)}{z^4}$$

How do I transform the circumference $1+e^{i\theta}$?

Is there any other way?

Comment: $g(z) = z^2 \log(1+z)$ is analytic on $|z-1| < 2$ so that $\int_{|z-1| = 1} g(z)dz = 0$. So it reduces to finding a primitive of $h(z) = z^2 \log(1-z)$ on the appropriate domain

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{\verts{z - 1} = 1}z^{2}\ln\pars{z + 1 \over z - 1}\,\dd z 
\,\,\,\stackrel{z - 1\ \mapsto\ z}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}\pars{z + 1}^{2}\ln\pars{1 + {2 \over z}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] \stackrel{z\ \mapsto\ 1/z}{=}\,\,\,&
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}\pars{{1 \over z} + 1}^{2}\ln\pars{1 + 2z}
\,{\dd z \over z^{2}} =
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2} \over z^{4}}\ln\pars{1 + 2z}
\,\dd z
\\[3mm] = &\
2\pi\ic\,{1 \over 2!}\ \overbrace{\lim_{z \to 0}\totald[2]{}{z}
{\pars{1 + z}^{2}\ln\pars{2z + 1} \over z}}^{\ds{4 \over 3}}\ -\
\int_{-1}^{-1/2}
{\pars{1 + x}^{2} \over x^{4}}\bracks{\ln\pars{-1 - 2x} + \pi\ic}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] - &\
\int_{-1/2}^{-1}
{\pars{1 + x}^{2} \over x^{4}}\bracks{\ln\pars{-1 - 2x} - \pi\ic}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] = &\
{4 \over 3}\,\pi\ic - 2\pi\ic\
\overbrace{\int_{1/2}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}^{2} \over x^{4}}\,\dd x}^{\ds{1 \over 3}}
=\
\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{{2 \over 3}\,\pi\ic}}
\end{align}

Comment: Felix, this solution uses the principal branches for $\log(z+1)$ and $\log(z-1)$.  As I showed in my post, the value of the integral is dependent on the choice of branch cut.  I give two examples, one of which uses the principal branches and yields $i2\pi/3$, and the other uses a different branch cut for $\log(z-1)$ and yields $-i14\pi/3$$.

Answer (score 1):

> The integral
>
> $$I=\oint_{|z-1|=1}z^2\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz\tag 1$$
>
> is ***not*** uniquely defined unless we prescribe a branch for the complex logarithm.

---

> **BRANCH CUT CHOICE $1$:**

If we decide to cut the plane from $-1$ to $1$ with a "slit" along the real axis, then we have

$$\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz=\log\left|\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right|+i\arg\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$$

where $-\pi <\arg(z-1)\le \pi$, $-\pi <\arg(z+1)\le \pi$, and for $|z-1|=1$, $-\pi< \arg\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\le \pi$.

We can evaluate the integral $I$ a number of ways.  If we choose to use the parametric description $z=1+e^{i\phi}$, $-\pi <\phi\le \pi$, then

$$\begin{align}
I&=\underbrace{\int_{-\pi}^\pi (1+e^{i\phi})^2 \log(2+e^{i\phi})\,ie^{i\phi}\,d\phi}_{=0\,\text{since}\,z^2\log(1+z)\,\text{is analytic}}-\int_{-\pi}^\pi (1+e^{i\phi})^2 \log(e^{i\phi})\,ie^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \phi (e^{i\phi}+2e^{i2\phi}+e^{i3\phi})\,d\phi\\\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi} \phi(\sin(\phi)+2\sin(2\phi)+\sin(3\phi))\,d\phi\\\\
&=i2\pi/3
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, we can use Cauchy's integral theorem to evaluate $(1)$.  We deform the contour $|z-1|=1$ around the branch cut and find that

$$\begin{align}0&=\int_{|z-1|=1}z^2\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz\\\\
&+\int_0^1 x^2 \left(\log\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)-i\pi\right)\,dx\\\\
&-\int_0^1 x^2 \left(\log\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)+i\pi\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{|z-1|=1}z^2\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz-i2\pi/3
\end{align}$$

whence we find that $I=i2\pi/3$ as expected.

---

> **BRANCH CUT CHOICE $2$:**

If instead, we decide to cut the plane with the two branch cuts from (i) $-1$ to $-\infty$ and (ii) from $1$ to $\infty$ along the real axis, then we have

$$\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz=\log\left|\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right|+i\arg\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$$

where $-\pi <\arg(z-1)\le \pi$, $0 <\arg(z+1)\le 2\pi$, and for $|z-1|=1$, $0< \arg\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\le 2\pi$.

If we choose to use the parametric description $z=1+e^{i\phi}$, $0 <\phi\le 2\pi$, then

$$\begin{align}
I&=\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi} (1+e^{i\phi})^2 \log(2+e^{i\phi})\,ie^{i\phi}\,d\phi}_{=0\,\text{since}\,z^2\log(1+z)\,\text{is analytic}}-\int_0^{2\pi} (1+e^{i\phi})^2 \log(e^{i\phi})\,ie^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \phi (e^{i\phi}+2e^{i2\phi}+e^{i3\phi})\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \phi(\cos(\phi)+2\cos(2\phi)+\cos(3\phi))\,d\phi+i\int_0^{2\pi} \phi(\sin(\phi)+2\sin(2\phi)+\sin(3\phi))\,d\phi\\\\
&=-i14\pi/3
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, we can use Cauchy's integral theorem to evaluate $(1)$.  We deform the contour $|z-1|=1$ around the branch cut and find that

$$\begin{align}0&=\int_{|z-1|=1}z^2\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz\\\\
&+\int_1^2 x^2 \left(\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)\right)\,dx\\\\
&-\int_1^2 x^2 \left(\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)-i2\pi\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{|z-1|=1}z^2\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz+i14\pi/3
\end{align}$$

whence we find that $I=-i14\pi/3$ as expected.

---

> **We have shown that the value of the integral $I$ depends on our choice of branch for the complex logarithm.  The reason for the different values is not surprising given that the logarithm function itself is different on the different Riemann sheets.**

Comment: I got $2\pi\,\mathrm{i}/3$ which is the $\texttt{Mathematica}$ result too.

Comment: @felixmarin Felix, as I showed, the answer depends on how we choose to define the logarithm function.  Evidently, you and Mathematica cut the plane such that the principal branches of $\log(z+1)$ and $\log)z-1)$ are used.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

$g(z)=z^2 (\log(1+z)-i\pi)$ is analytic on $|z-1| < 2$ so that $\int_{|z-1| = 1} g(z)dz = 0$.

Thus, it reduces to finding a primitive of $$h(z) = -z^2 \log(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n+2}}{n}$$ ie. $$H(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n+3}}{n(n+3)}=\frac13\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n+3} (\frac{1}{n+3}-\frac{1}{n}) \\ =-\frac13 z^3\log(1-z)+ \frac13 (\log(1-z)-z-\frac{z^2}{2})$$ 
Finally, being careful with the branches, and using that $H(1+ze^{2i\pi}) =H(1+z)- \frac{z^3-1}{3}2i\pi$
 $$\int_{|z-1|=1} z^2 \log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz=\int_{|z-1|=1} (g(z)+h(z))dz = \int_{|z-1|=1} h(z)dz  = H(1+1)-H(1+ e^{2i\pi})\\= \frac{7}{3} 2i \pi$$
or something like that

Comment: @MarkViola I'm using that $H(1+ze^{2i\pi}) =H(1+z)- \frac{z^3-1}{3}2i\pi$ so finding the mistake shouldn't be difficult

Comment: The answer depends on the choice of branch cut for $\log(z-1)$.

Comment: I've posted a solution that shows the value of the integral is dependent on how we define the complex logarithm through choice of branch cut.  Your answer has embedded a tacit choice of branch cuts.

Comment: I got $2\pi\,\mathrm{i}/3$ which is the $\texttt{Mathematica}$ result too.